# Refactoring non REST complient requests

Tags: java, angular, rest

I'm working on a reporting system which services chart data via web service calls. In some cases a search is done, in others an update of configuration is done.

The UI side of the code happens to be Angular, the backend is Java with Oracle serving as the persistence store.  Interestingly, there is NO Java persistence framework being used beyond ordinary JDBC. However, my question isn't about any of those things at least directly.

Nearly all of the requests for things like a resource are made with a POST request. So, getting data for a particular report be a POST request with the status coming back in a JSON based response (OK for it worked, or ERROR for it didn't).

This is not my understanding of REST standards. I would have thought the developer should make GET requests for resources, supplying inputs via either query string parameters or request headers.  Calls which alter the state or a resource would be made via POST or PUT.

What are the consequences to not following these standards and just rolling our own paradigm and just POSTing everything?

Comment: Nothing happen if your application work well even if you are not following these standards , all of your request could be post , but if you follow these standars your api cleaner and easy for any one that want to use those api and for application to connect with them. just google rest api benefits or advantages of rest api

Comment: Most of these so-called REST services or APIs are RPC based anyways. The worst thing that can happen is that clients will not be able to interact with your servie further until they got adapted to work with the API again. For a simple backend-to-frontend communication, REST is overkill. REST should be used in cases where you have a multitude of clients not under your control and where you know that the system will change over time and you need the freedom to change on the serverside (think of a message-broker in the domain of EDI with lots of ERP system connected to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the consequences to not following these standards and just rolling our own paradigm and just POSTing everything?

What you give up are the advantages that generic components can provide when they understand that a request is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1).

For example, web browsers can optimize the user experience by proactively fetching representations of resources you might want.

Similarly, on an unstable network, if a response is lost, a generic component can know to retry the request - because the semantics of the request promise that there is no risk in doing so.

Furthermore, if everything is a POST, then you are constantly evicting representations from your HTTP aware cache.  [Caching constraints](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) are important in the REST architectural style - the fact that we can download a representation from the network once and then re-use it is a critical part of scaling the web.

One of the interesting corners of the HTTP specification, is that `304 Not Modified` is not one of the [allowed response codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) for a POST request.  There's no analog to Conditional GET.

When everything is `POST`, you are taking an application protocol and turning it into a dumb message tunnel, offering to generic components only the weakest possible semantic description of what is going on.

That doesn't necessarily mean that using POST for everything is wrong.  SOAP went that route, and GraphQL seems to be heading that way as well.  HTTP isn't optimized for remote procedure call style, but it is capable.

Comment: I upvoted one answer, but still would like to hear from others as well. If you have something else not said, please add it. I appreciate the education.